# Flutter firebase push notification on click when the app is in the terminated state

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, flutter-getx

I have integrated firebase push notifications into an app where users can log in and do stuff. Once the user logs in, it will take the user to the home screen and it will stay in the logged-in state even though the user terminates the app and opened the app again.

I wanted to handle push notification clicks (when in the terminated state) and direct the user to a specific route. The issue is, whenever click on the notification, it always takes me to the initial route, which is supposed to be the home screen.

As I found on the internet, I used the below code to direct the user to the home screen, but still, it doesn't work.

The real need is to take the user to another specific route according to the message content, but it doesn't even take me to the home screen.

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((initialMessage) {
  if (initialMessage != null) {
    Get.toNamed('/home');
  }
});


    List<GetPage> buildRoutes = [
  GetPage(
    name: '/',
    page: () => InitHelper(),
  ),
  GetPage(
    name: '/auth',
    page: () => InitialScreen(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
  ),
  GetPage(
    name: '/home',
    page: () => TabsPage(selectedIndex: 0),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
  ),
]

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(375, 812),
        builder: (context, _) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'App Name',
            initialRoute: '/',
            getPages: buildRoutes,
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: Do you have routes set up [somewhere](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#navigation-with-named-routes)?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele Yes, I have. Exactly like the reference you mentioned.

Comment: Please post your routes.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele Updated the post. In the initial route, I handle the auth and set accessToken to session and call a few APIs and according to verifications, it should navigate to the home page.